# Changing menus (ribbon) font in Matlab R2013

Tags: matlab

Just started using Matlab R2013 , and found its new ribbon interface for menus. 
This UI's font is really tiny to work with at high resolutions, and I don't see how it can be changed (Other fonts like the Command Window's or the Editor can be changed with no problem, like always.

Comment: I don't know if this can be changed. If you don't find a solution, a usability case (or lack thereof) like this should be [reported to the MathWorks](http://mathworks.com/support/service_requests/contact_support.do). This probably means that the text is not only hard to read on high resolution monitors, but also for those with vision problems. The MathWorks should be testing their interfaces for accessibility and using standard practices, but I wouldn't be surprised if they didn't do much (in OS X, the native accessibility features already don't work due to the use of Java UI).